# Proportion in sets

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, approximation

We have $3$ sets of positive integers.

$$A = \{x_1,y_2,z_3\},\quad{} B = \{x_2,y_2,z_2\}, \quad{} C= \{x,y,z\}$$

Which proportion do we use for adding $A$ and $B$ ($x_1+x_2$ and so on), so the proportion in their numbers gets as close as possible to the proportion of the numbers in $C$ ($x,y,z$ make a proportion) ?

Comment: i don't understand. an example would be helpful. Also what does it mean that $x,y,z$ make a proportion? $x/y = y/z$?

Comment: I have an aunt, that wants to buy fruits in certain proportion 5 bananas, 3 apples and 7 oranges from 2 different friends that sell boxes with bananas apples and oranges. The first friend J sells fruit boxes with 2 bananas, 5 apples and 6 oranges. The second friend sells fruit boxes with 4 bananas, 2 apples and 7 oranges. My aunt has to constantly buy the fruit (no limit of amount) the point however is that she wants to buy the boxes from her friends in the optimal proportion so the amount of fruit she gets is as close as possible to the proportion of fruits she wants. (5,3,7)

Comment: @Jimmy If order matters, use 3-tuples, not sets.

Comment: order does not matter, as in the example, it could be 5 bananas, 3 apples, and 7 oranges or 3 apples, 5 bananas and 7 oranges. It is a very practical problem.

Comment: Your aunt wants 1.4 times as many oranges as bananas. One seller gives 3 times as many, the other 1.75 times as many. So it is impossible to get close to the desired ratio. So you have to decide exactly what you mean by "as close as possible" (given that you are trying to approximate three ratios simultaneously).

Answer (score 1):

Let's make some assumptions about things to approach this problem. We need a notion of comparing proportions, so let's say, given two triples $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$, they are in-proportion equivalent to $(1, b/a, c/a)$ and $(1, e/d. f/d)$, so I will use the 2-norm to measure the difference and say that the distance $D$ between $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$ is
$$
D = \sqrt{\left(\frac{b}{a} - \frac{e}{d}\right)^2
         +\left(\frac{c}{a} - \frac{f}{d}\right)^2}.
$$
We could have used a different metric (e.g. rescaling by 2nd or 3rd coordinate), but let's settle on this definition for now.

Then, given
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{pmatrix},
B = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2 \end{pmatrix},
C = \begin{pmatrix} x   \\ y   \\ z   \end{pmatrix},
$$
we let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and we can see that using a linear combination $aA + bB$ to approach $C$, we get to compare
$$
aA + bB
 = \begin{pmatrix} ax_1 + bx_2 \\ ay_1 + by_2 \\ az_1 + bz_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
to $C$, which using our metric yields the distance of
$$
D^2 = \left(\frac{ay_1 + by_2}{ax_1 + bx_2} - \frac{y}{x}\right)^2
         +\left(\frac{az_1 + bz_2}{ax_1 + bx_2} - \frac{z}{x}\right)^2.
$$
Dividing numerator and denominator of both fractions by $a$ and letting $d = b/a$, we get
$$
D^2(d) = \left(\frac{y_1 + dy_2}{x_1 + dx_2} - \frac{y}{x}\right)^2
         +\left(\frac{z_1 + dz_2}{ax_1 + dx_2} - \frac{z}{x}\right)^2,
$$
where all elements except $d$ are fixed and the problem reduces to minimizing $D^2(d)$ (which is equivalent to minimizing $D(d)$ but easier) over all $d \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Hope you can finish this from here.